# Zooming and moving a UIScrollView at the same time

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a UIScrollView that takes up a portion of the screen, and its basic functions (scrolling and zooming) work just fine.  For example, I can grab the scrollview with two fingers, and scroll left and right, while zooming in or out on the content.

I want to add the ability to move the UIScrollView up and down at the same time.  Please note that I do not want to move the **content** of the scroll view, but the scroll view itself.

I have attempted to add a UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the UIScrollView which has allowed me to grab and move the scroll view, but I then lose the zoom and scrolling.  It seems that adding a gesture recognizer makes all of the default actions stop (also, when I call setZoomScale, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

I've also considered checking touches, but touches on the UIScrollView aren't registered with the main view so I can't change its location using those values.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this might be accomplished?

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate touches that will move the `UIScrollView` from touches that will pan/zoom?

Comment: I guess that's the whole issue. I thought a GestureRecognizer could be allowed to let the touches through, but that doesn't seem to work quite right.  I've read about subclassing `UIScrollView` and maybe pass back the touches to the view controller -- not sure if that will allow me to do what I want and still have the `UIScrollView` behave normally.

Comment: Wel, I think you'll face an issue that is less one of "permission" and more one of "practicality". Unless you have a button/switch/etc... that changes modes, I think you'll find it difficult to differentiate between a "pan swipe" and a "move swipe".